# Componente joomsocial causa erro "class 'CAccess' does not have a method 'authorise'"

Tags: php, joomla

Eu instalei o joomsocial em meu joomla, porem quando eu conclui a instalação o seguinte erro aparece:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'CAccess' does not have a method 'authorise' in /home/swingudi/public_html/social/components/com_community/helpers/access.php on line 74

Comment: Boa noite, qual versão do joomlasocial e do joomla esta usando (NÃO COMENTE) e como fez a tal instalação do componente, edite a pergunta e coloque informações importantes como esta pra que seja possivel conseguirmos lhe ajudar. Provavelmente você instalou uma versão que não é compativel com o Joomla que esta usando.

Comment: Outra dica, todo veem aqui procurando ajuda, escrever no titulo coisas como "Ajuda", "por favor", "Help" é totalmente irrelevante. Crie titulos relevantes ao topico da pergunta. Tenho certeza que vai levar o meu comentário como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Wellington, observe os comentários deixados por outros usuários em suas perguntas pois eles geralmente dão boas dicas de como evitar o fechamento e deixar sua pergunta com uma qualidade maior. Justamente por você ter várias perguntas fechadas recentemente o sistema acabou te bloqueando de perguntar. Se você conseguir fazer com que sua pergunta seja reaberta esse bloqueio do sistema deve ser suspenso logo em seguida.

Comment: Ola realmente esta relacionada a versão do joomla, o erro ocorreu apos a atualização do mesmo, eu tenho a versão 3 do joomsocial,
O problema é que eu estou tentando instalar a verção mais antiga do joomla mas não esta dando certo, não completa a instalação

Comment: Acho que não leu o comentário eu disse NÃO COMENTE, edite a pergunta, de detalhes, informe as versões exatas que esta usando do Joomla e do componente, **por favor leia com mais atenção**, as dicas aqui são pra tentar lhe ajudar a melhorar a pergunta pra que consigamos um parâmetro por onde começar a detectar o problema o seu problema, comente coisas relevantes apenas, por exemplo respostas a outros comentários. Tenho certeza que vai levar o meu comentário como uma critica construtiva. :)

Comment: Eu não entendi a edição do titulo e nem a tag Helper, vou fazer o rollback. Titulos devem ser intuitivos.

Answer (score 1):

Simples, sua classe não tem um método chamado "authorise". Você precisa definir este método na classe ou ele pode ser privado, neste último só poderá ser chamado de dentro da própria classe. Procure especificar melhor sua pergunta, isso vai nos ajudar a responder.

Comment: Ola amigo é que eu sou designer e não entendo muito sobre php, pra falar a verdade eu ainda nao entedi o que voce quis dizer com o metodo de chamado

Comment: onde eu devo ir para mudar

Comment: Pois é, @Wellington, este é um site para programadores, um mínimo de conhecimento da sua parte é necessário.

Comment: mas é desta forma que vou aprendendo